# Create variant array using Text instead of Value

Tags: vba, excel

In [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) you can create a variant array from a range like so:

```
Dim x As Variant

x = Range("A1:Z1").Value
```

This will obviously place the `.Value` properties into the array. I'm trying to do the same thing but get the `.Text` property of the cells instead, but I don't think it's possible.

```
Dim x As Variant

x = Range("A1:Z1").Text '// <~~ type mismatch
```

---

The reason is as follows, I have a row of data like so:

```
  |------A------|------B------|------C------|
 1| 01-Jan-2003   27-Feb-2005   15-Sep-2015
```

I want to output the row to a text file with a pipe delimiter, currently I'm using this:

```
With WorksheetFunction
    x = .Transpose(.Transpose(Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value))
End With

Print #1, Join(x, "|")
```

Which works, but it's getting the `.Value` which is formatted as dd/mm/yyyy so the output looks like this:

> ```
> 01/01/2003|27/02/2005|15/09/2015
> ```

---

***Q:*** Can I retain the formatting using this method without having to parse/loop each value in the array first?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to loop through the values if possible, in reality it's a bunch of considerably large files so a loop would have a significant impact on the processing time. I've updated my question to reflect that as it wasn't immediately clear tbf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant and I'm not sure how well this would work in bulk but it avoids a loop. You could put the final output into a string and replace:

```
Dim x As Variant, y As String

x = Range("A1:Z1")

With WorksheetFunction
    x = .Transpose(.Transpose(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value))
End With

y = Join(x, "|")

y = Replace(y, "/01/", "-Jan-")
y = Replace(y, "/02/", "-Feb-")
y = Replace(y, "/03/", "-Mar-")
y = Replace(y, "/04/", "-Apr-")
y = Replace(y, "/05/", "-May-")
y = Replace(y, "/06/", "-Jun-")
y = Replace(y, "/07/", "-Jul-")
y = Replace(y, "/08/", "-Aug-")
y = Replace(y, "/09/", "-Sep-")
y = Replace(y, "/10/", "-Oct-")
y = Replace(y, "/11/", "-Nov-")
y = Replace(y, "/12/", "-Dec-")

Debug.print y
```

Comment: I actually ended up having to loop as there were intermittent whitespace characters that needed tidying up with `Trim$()` but this would have definitely been an acceptable solution so I'll accept it

Comment: Could even do a mini `For i = 1 To 12` loop/replace which would still be quicker than looping through all the values in the array